# How to create/implement a R script in Spotfire to add the commas to a converted string number?

Tags: r, spotfire

In a Spotfire report, after a REAL number converted to a string, the commas got lost. How to create and implement an R script to add the commas in the converted number?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  We would love to help but need more information from you.  Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In this case all we would really need is examples: what you have tried, what you want to happen, etc. Take a look at [how to write a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try `prettyNum(x, big.mark = ",")` where `x` is numeric (not character).

Answer (score 0):

You don't to use `R` for this. You should convert it back either in the presentation of your analytic, or create a calculated column and change the formatting.

1. Insert > Calculated Column: `Real([YourStringColumn])`
2. Edit > Column Properties > YourNewColumn > Formatting > Number: Check `Use thousands separator`

Of note, I'm interested in the following

1. How did a `Real` number get converted to a `String` and
2. Why did this conversion drop the commas? I'd think it would keep them.